# WPF Databinding intellisense

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, intellisense

Ok, so I have a general question about WPF. I've messed a little with ASP.NET MVC and in the markup it has intellisense on your viewmodel object so you don't mistype it( i love it).

Enter WPF, I love it, I'm utilizing the MVVM approach and one annoying thing that I have to do is make sure I'm binding correctly to my viewmodel. So I type something up in my xaml, then I either
1) if I'm lazy just run the app and click around 
2) If i'm not lazy
   a)Look at the current DataContext of the control I'm working with.
   b)Go to that ViewModel class look at the properties
   c)Find my property and then click back to my view and make sure that I spelled it correctly.

I believe that you can look at your trace output for incorrect bindings at run time, but is there something in the horizon to allow intellisense in xaml. The View needs to know about my ViewModel, so why not expose that in xaml.

I think it would be nice for the IDE to do that for me, meaning, when I type **"{Binding "** it should go up the visual tree find the first non-null DataContext and display the properties, let me select one and there you have it.

Am I missing something? Are there any alternatives. Any insight?

EDIT:

Regarding the comments below there is a way to set the datacontext at design time e.g.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DesignTimeData:DesignTimeCustomers x:Key="designTimeCustomersDS" />
</Window.Resources>
```

which is a snippet from this blog:
http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2008/10/11/viewing-design-time-data-in-visual-studio-2008-cider-designer-in-wpf-and-silverlight-projects/

All it does is reference a class within xaml.

So with that in place could not the designer then utilize reflection on the datacontext to give you all of the properties for that class?

Comment: In some ways WPF really shines - in others it's a POS. This is one of those others.

Comment: That's why I'm using tests to validate all (well, almost all) view bindings against corresponding ViewModels.

Comment: As already suggested below, use Resharper (with d:DataContext set), it will save you a lot of time. you can directly generate viewmodel properties from xaml with alt+enter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So with that in place could not the
>   designer then utilize reflection on
>   the datacontext to give you all of the
>   properties for that class?

Resharper 6 has this feature and can  show you members of the d:DataContext in the intellisense, if you set the d:DataContext on the View.

Answer (score 7):

[VS 2013:](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2013/08/09/xaml-editor-improvements-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx)

IntelliSense with resolved DataContext
[image]

IntelliSense with design time DataContext
[image]

Comment: Nice, this fixed it for me using VS2017. Had to add a reference to the namespace in my Window:  xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:my.viewmodel.namespace" and then set the design time viewmodel on the Window: d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vm:MyViewModel}". I now have intellisense on my bindings even though the DataContext is initialised in external code.

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio 2010 will support intellisense on Bindings.  However, this is limited to the properties of the Binding object itself.  For example after typing "{Binding " into the XAML editor I then get intellisense on the remaining properties (Path, ElementName, etc.).

I don't think the type of intellisense regarding the data context you specified would be possible as the data context is set at run-time.  I've tried experimenting in VS 2010 by setting the data context directly in the constructor but did not have any luck.

Comment: Here's the link for the MIX09 video that goes over some of this, fast forward to around 20min to get into the Resource Picker and intellisence: http://videos.visitmix.com/MIX09/T73M

Comment: Given that the DataContext is set a run time, I doubt that it's possible to implement intellisense for bindings, unfortunately. Just because the type of the variable set as the DataContext is Foo, it could really be a Bar and Bar's properties are fair game to use for bindings. How could Visual Studio know this to be the case?

Comment: I made some updates above that basically indicates that we can assign the datacontext in design time. But from your comments, it seems this isn't on the horizon.

Answer (score 2):

According to :

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2013/08/09/xaml-editor-improvements-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx

Visual studio 2013 xaml Editor now  is supporting IntelliSense for Data Binding

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2010 there is a binding builder which you can enable
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/14/how-to-enable-using-the-binding-builder-in-wpf-and-silverlight-applications.aspx
but you still don't get intellisense which is weird.